# How does rendering to multiple textures work in modern OpenGL?

Tags: opengl, framebuffer, deferred-rendering

If I understand FBOs correctly, I can attach several 2D textures to different color attachment points. I'd like to use this capability to write out a few different types of data from a fragment shader (e.g. world position and normals). It looks like in ye olden days, this involved writing to gl_FragData at different indices, but gl_FragData doesn't exist anymore. How is this done now?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just add output variables to your fragment shader. Here is an example:

```
layout(location=0) out vec4 color;
layout(location=1) out vec3 normal;
layout(location=2) out vec3 position;

void main() {
    color = vec4(1,0,0,1);
    normal = vec3(0,1,0);
    position = vec3(1,2,3);
}
```

Comment: This roughly works, but I hit some oddities: if alpha blending is enabled, the COLOR_ATTACHMENTi outputs need to be vec4, so that alpha can be set to nonzero. I also haven't managed to get `int` or `ivec` to work at all (my awful solution is to cast everything to floats).

Answer (score 2):

As dari said, you can use the `layout(location=0)` specifier.

Another method to assign the location outside of the shader is to use:

```
glBindFragDataLocation(_program, 0, "color");
```

Then in the shader:

```
out vec4 color;
```

See this for a more thorough discussion of output buffers:
https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Fragment_Shader#Output_buffers